# "No matching function for call to bind" while using websocketpp

Tags: c++, boost, websocket, boost-bind

I'm making an (c++) application which is a websocket client and websocket server. To be able to do this, I'm using the library websocketpp. To make the application both a client and server, I want the `endpoint1.run()` and `endpoint2.listen(port)` to be multi-threaded. This is where something goes wrong.

Normally (single thread) I use: `endpoint.listen(port);` which works.

To make it into a multi-thread I use:

```
boost::thread t(boost::bind(&server::listen, &endpoint, port));
sleep(1);
cout << "After thread! \n";
t.join();
```

However, I get the error:

`main.cpp:116: error: no matching function for call to ‘bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, websocketpp::server*, uint16_t&)’`

`server::listen` is an overloaded function, should I call it differently in bind?

Comment: Is there more than one server::listen method?

Comment: yes, four. How can I point to the right one?

Comment: It is ugly, but possible. see the link in the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/bind/bind.html#err_overloaded). There is a good example.
You need to resolve the ambiguity by your self.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still wondering how to implement this:

```c
void(websocketpp::role::server<websocketpp::server>::*f)(uint16_t,size_t) = &websocketpp::role::server<websocketpp::server>::listen;

boost::thread t(f, &endpoint, port, 1); //No need to use boost::bind here
```

and after that call t.detach() or endpoint.stop() and t.join()