# I get error unresolved overloaded function type in c++

Tags: c++, boost

Why would piece of code like this:

```
boost::bind (SomeFunc<float>, function arguments go here);
```

produce this error:

```
no matching function for call to bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>
```

THanks

Comment: @user1486293 - that doesn't stop you from creating a small, but real example that shows the problem, see for example the code I showed in my answer: you can reduce your problem to something that sort of size too

Comment: possible duplicate of ["No matching function for call to bind" while using websocketpp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734236/no-matching-function-for-call-to-bind-while-using-websocketpp)

Answer (score 9):

It could be that your function `SomeFunc<float>` is overloaded, in which case `boost::bind` cannot deal with this. You have to implement a manual solution, see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/bind/bind.html#err_overloaded) for more details:

Comment: But my function is not member of class or struct.

Comment: @user1486293 Doesn't matter - you still need to use a `static_cast` to resolve the ambiguity

Comment: @user1486293 it doesn't matter if it is a member function. The compiler cannot resolve which overload you want so you have to help it along.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a `static_cast` to tell the compiler which overload to pick if it's ambiguous, e.g.:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

void foo(int) {}
void foo(double) {}

int main() {
  boost::bind(static_cast<void(*)(int)>(&foo), _1);
}
```

Sometimes *"unresolved overloaded function type"* can mean "none of the overloads are viable" in which case you need to figure out why it can't use any and fix that.

Comment: And what if foo is template function?

Comment: @user1486293 - same thing with `static_cast` applies if it's ambiguous. Be careful it's not actually complaining that none of the versions of `foo` are viable instead.