# BOOST-ASIO blocking server does not respond to blocking client?

Tags: c++, tcp, client-server, boost-asio

I recently had this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697082/cboost-bind-error-no-matching-function-for-call-to-bindunresolved-overloa#) solved for the server in question but it turns out the server does not seem to reply back to the client nor does it even receive any data sent in the first place. This is what I did on the client side.

```
C:\blocking_tcp_echo_client\bin\Debug>blocking_tcp_echo_client 127.0.0.1 4001
Enter message: hello
Exception: read: End of file
```

this was the server side. I did start the server before starting the client. I also tested the client with the original [code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/blocking_tcp_echo_server.cpp) and it worked fine.

```
C:\boost_server_class\bin\Debug>boost_server_class
TCPIP_server:
Usage: blocking_tcp_echo_server
```

blocking_tcp_echo_client.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

enum { max_length = 1024 };

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc != 3)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: blocking_tcp_echo_client <host> <port>\n";
      return 1;
    }

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    tcp::resolver::query query(tcp::v4(), argv[1], argv[2]);
    tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

    tcp::socket s(io_service);
    s.connect(*iterator);

    using namespace std; // For strlen.
    std::cout << "Enter message: ";
    char request[max_length];
    std::cin.getline(request, max_length);
    size_t request_length = strlen(request);
    boost::asio::write(s, boost::asio::buffer(request, request_length));

    char reply[max_length];
    size_t reply_length = boost::asio::read(s,
        boost::asio::buffer(reply, request_length));
    std::cout << "Reply is: ";
    std::cout.write(reply, reply_length);
    std::cout << "\n";
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

boost_server_class.cpp

```
#include "TCPIP_server.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"TCPIP_server:"<<std::endl;
    TCPIP_server server;

    server.main_server();

    return 0;
}
```

TCPIP_server.h

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

const int max_length = 1024;

class TCPIP_server
{
        private:

            typedef boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> socket_ptr;
            char data[max_length];

        public:

        TCPIP_server(){}
        ~TCPIP_server(){}
        void session(socket_ptr sock)
        {
            std::cout<<"TCPIP_server session:"<<std::endl;
            try
            {
                for (;;)
                {
                    char data[max_length];

                    boost::system::error_code error;
                    size_t length = sock->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data), error);
                    if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
                        break; // Connection closed cleanly by peer.
                    else if (error)
                        throw boost::system::system_error(error); // Some other error.

                    boost::asio::write(*sock, boost::asio::buffer(data, length));
                }
            }
            catch (std::exception& e)
            {
                std::cerr << "Exception in thread: " << e.what() << "\n";
            }
        }
        void server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port)
        {
            tcp::acceptor a(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port));

            for (;;)
            {
                socket_ptr sock(new tcp::socket(io_service));
                a.accept(*sock);
                boost::bind(&TCPIP_server::session, this, sock);
            }
        }
        void main_server()
        {
            try
            {
                std::cerr << "Usage: blocking_tcp_echo_server \n";
                boost::asio::io_service io_service;

                using namespace std; // For atoi.
                server(io_service, atoi("4001"));
            }
            catch (std::exception& e)
            {
                std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
            }
        }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your server is broken.**

After you accept a connection, you create an unnamed functor bound to `TCPIP_server::session()` that is never invoked. The accepted socket will immediately go out of scope, which closes it and your client sees `eof`.

```
socket_ptr sock(new tcp::socket(io_service));
a.accept(*sock);
boost::bind(&TCPIP_server::session, this, sock); // <-- this does nothing
```

You could resolve this by removing the functor, and instead invoking `this->session( sock )` after accepting the connection. I wouldn't suggest this approach however, your server is single threaded so it will be unable to service additional clients after the first has connected. Instead I suggest following the [async echo sever example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp) and rewrite your server using a single thread, a single `io_service`, and async methods.

Comment: But the client can be the same right, I guess this is what they mean by blocking server. I never understood that part.

Comment: @lost your client is ok, as evident by your comment that it works fine with the asio blocking echo server.

Comment: Ok.  The async server isnt threaded. Do I just put the session into the thread like the blocking tcp server?

Comment: @lost the async echo server uses a single thread, the one invoking main(). The blocking echo server creates a new thread for each connection.

Comment: I read this link http://www.nightmare.com/medusa/async_sockets.html and I wondered what the point would be for the async server having multiple threads if each client is already handled in the queue as a `new` connection? I'm also having trouble coding the actual async threaded server since I'm not totally familiar with boosts asio framework. No worries though I'm sure I could figure out the coding part.

Comment: I'm starting to realize I don't need to do anything to the async server code, its already what I need, I guess.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27575/discussion-between-lost-with-coding-and-sam-miller)